# iOS: Remove back button text from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to customize my `UIImagePickerController`'s status bar appearance. I have a custom image I'm using for the back button, which properly appears, but what I'd like to do is remove the text (so it's just the image). I regularly do this throughout my app, but I can't seem to get it working in the `UIImagePickerController`.

I figured I could do something like...

```
UIImagePickerController *uiipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
uiipc.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

However that does not seem to work, when selecting a folder e.g. "Photos" I still get the custom image with the text "Photos" next to it for the back button.

Could someone give me a hand removing the text?

EDIT: Worth noting that the custom image is set in my app delegate, which is why you don't see that in my example.

Answer (score 9):

You could use appearance proxy method:

```
UIOffset backButtonTextOffset = UIOffsetMake(0, -60);
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:backButtonTextOffset
                                                        forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

this will take out title text way. See the attached image for iOS 7.
[image: sampel image]

Comment: Hmm, feels a bit hacky but it works. I'm going leave it unanswered for a few more hours then probably select your solution. Thank you.

Comment: This has a downside, if you have title on this navigation bar. See the title shift a bit to right.